# Anchoring controls within a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, anchor, panel

My form contains a panel which is used to add/dispose of several user controls (based on the selection of from the menustrip). Prior to using this panel to contain each user control, I could anchor and therefore resize each user control when the form resized. Despite the panel resizing correctly with the form, I can't figure out how to anchor the user controls within the panel so that they will also resize.

Example of panel in yellow, user control in red: http://gyazo.com/390f85587335efee4a9ec8b913ffce06

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
disposeUCs()

        Dim _UCAddNewRawMaterial As New UCAddNewRawMaterial
        Panel1.Controls.Add(_UCAddNewRawMaterial)
```

Comment: We don't have enough information here to help you.  **HOW** do you want the multiple(?) UserControls within this Panel resized?  So they take up equal space horizontally, vertically, in a grid?...something else?  Take a look at the [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for something to start with.

Comment: Can you show code on how you are creating a control and adding it to the Panel?

Comment: I've edited the question to show how my user controls are added to the panel- disposeUCs() simply removes the current user control from the panel when a new user control has been selected for viewing. Please look at the image link I've provided in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll only ever have **one** UserControl in the Panel at a time?

If so, simply [DockStyle.Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it:

```
Dim _UCAddNewRawMaterial As New UCAddNewRawMaterial
_UCAddNewRawMaterial.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Panel1.Controls.Add(_UCAddNewRawMaterial)
```

Comment: Yes only one User Control at once- this appears to have worked! Thank you for your help.